# Pass multiple optional parameters to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller Action that returns a list of activities to a view. (eventID,Venue,Room,EventDescription,EventType,StartDateTime,EndDateTime). The users wanted to be able to filter by Venue so I added Venue as id to the action method

```
ActionResult ListEvents(id string)
{
    ... Get the relevant details and return the view with the model
}
```

Now they want to also be able to filter by any/all of Event Type, Start, End, whether Post-event data has been completed.

Am I better to add these as GET query parameters or to define a custom route that will accept all 5 arguments or is there another solution

I will also need to add sorting and pagination at some point in case this changes the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, these would be handled via a query string, but it doesn't matter how you do it really. Regardless, of how the parameters are sent, your action simply needs to accept them all. The only thing you have to be aware of is the standard C# method rule (since actions are just methods) that optional parameters must be the last ones on the method. If they're *all* optional, then even that isn't really a concern.

Basically, you just have something like:

```
public ActionResult ListEvents(string id = null, int? eventID = null, ...)
{
```

Then inside, you'd just do something like:

```
var events = db.Events;

if (eventID.HasValue)
{
    events = events.Where(m => m.EventID == eventId);
} 

// rinse and repeat for each filter
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, Feels like it could do with being abstracted. Is it possible to read the GET parameters as a single array and iterate through the array elements to see if they match model properties?

Comment: No and no. You could create a view model that accepts all of those parameters as properties and bind to that instead, but you'd still need to check if each is set and filter accordingly one by one. The only other possibility is using reflection, but not only is that slow, but it may not even work in conjunction with EF, since where clauses need to be translatable to SQL.